# How to make google map Info Window transparent?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Working on an android application project which requires to show Google Map InfoWindow background to be transparent.

But I am not able to do it even after making layout for InfoWindow transparent it always show the default white pointer background.

Please suggest a solution, how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you to paste what you have tried (as text, not as image  and not as a link to another site) into your question (not as an answer). If you want your post to be taken in account for a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend creating a custom XML file for your InfoWindow.

1. Create a custom XML file (eg. windowlayout.xml)
2. Add:

   mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
             return null;
        }

   ```
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker arg0) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.windowlayout, null);
        TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        address.setText("Address: "+sAddress);
        TextView contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact);
                   info.setText("Contact Number: "+sContactNumber);
       return v;
    }
   ```

   });

You can make background transparent for this custom layout.
(I could not format the whole code, but the whole snippet is complete method)

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I was already doing all these what i was missing is providing background as '@android:color/transparent', now i changed it to take a transparent drawable '@drawable/transparentbg' and the code for _transparentbg.xml_ is   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>

Comment: Great :)!
You can even make it translucent!